# [gsoap][C] Undefined SOAP_TYPE_wchar

Tags: c, unicode, gsoap

I'm stuck with gsoap 2.7.13 (wsdl2h v1.2.1 and soapcpp2 v2.7.13). When I tried to map strings to wide chars in a pure C project, I get many compilation errors (SOAP_TYPE_wchar undefined).

Someone have experimented the same issue like me ?

Regards,

My typemap.dat

```
[
struct SOAP_ENV__Header
{
    _XML wsse__Security;
};
]

#   Use unicode
xsd__string = | wchar_t* | wchar_t*

#   CMIS recommended prefix
SOAP-ENV    =   "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope"
SOAP-ENC    =   "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding"
xsi         =   "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsd         =   "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
ns1         =   "http://docs.oasis-open.org/ns/cmis/core/200908/"
ns2         =   "http://docs.oasis-open.org/ns/cmis/messaging/200908/"
cmis        =   "http://docs.oasis-open.org/ns/cmis/ws/200908/"
cmis2       =   "http://docs.oasis-open.org/ns/cmis/ws/200908/DiscoveryServicePortBinding"
cmis3       =   "http://docs.oasis-open.org/ns/cmis/ws/200908/MultiFilingServicePortBinding"
cmis4       =   "http://docs.oasis-open.org/ns/cmis/ws/200908/NavigationServicePortBinding"
cmis5       =   "http://docs.oasis-open.org/ns/cmis/ws/200908/ObjectServicePortBinding"
cmis6       =   "http://docs.oasis-open.org/ns/cmis/ws/200908/PolicyServicePortBinding"
cmis7       =   "http://docs.oasis-open.org/ns/cmis/ws/200908/RelationshipServicePortBinding"
cmis8       =   "http://docs.oasis-open.org/ns/cmis/ws/200908/RepositoryServicePortBinding"
cmis9       =   "http://docs.oasis-open.org/ns/cmis/ws/200908/VersioningServicePortBinding"
cmis10      =   "http://docs.oasis-open.org/ns/cmis/ws/200908/ACLServicePortBinding"

# End of file
```

And my command lines :

```
wsdl2h -c -o cmis_ws.h -t typemap.dat -x "http://docs.oasis-open.org/cmis/CMIS/v1.0/errata-01/os/schemas/CMISWS-Service.wsdl"
soapcpp2 -c -p cmis cmis_ws.h
```

Comment: I compared the `cmisC.c` code generated by soapcpp2 with and without the line `xsd__string = | wchar_t* | wchar_t*` and it seems something is going wrong with arrays of `wchar_t`, which has a pointer to wide strings i.e. `wchar_t**` (see for example `ns1__cmisTypeRelationshipDefinitionType` in `cmis_ws.h`. A fix is needed in the old 2.7 version of soapcpp2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The patch to correct this issue:

1. edit `gsoap/src/symbol2.c` line 11201 and insert

```
  if (is_wstring(typ)) /* wchar_t* is serializable but wchar_t is transient */
    return 0;
```

The first part of function `is_transient` should look like this:

```
int
is_transient(Tnode *typ)
{
  if (!typ)
    return 1;
  if (typ->type == Tstruct && typ->id == lookup("soap"))
    return 1;
  if (is_external(typ) || is_volatile(typ))
    return 0;
  if (typ->transient > 0)
    return 1;
  if (is_wstring(typ)) /* wchar_t* is serializable but wchar_t is transient */
    return 0;
```

2. run `make` again, you can do this in the `gsoap/src` directory. This builds soapcpp2 in the `gsoap/src` directory. Copy soapcpp2 to your project or to a bin directory on your `$PATH`.